# Use %~n twice on a string in Batch

Tags: batch-file

I've got some for loops iterating over files listed in a text file. They have two extensions, like `filename.foo.bar`.

The first loop goes:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (bars.txt) do decompressBars.exe %%A
```

This decompresses the .bar extension and leaves all the files as `filename.foo`. Next,

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (bars.txt) do convertFoos.exe %%~nA %%~n~nA.baz
```

Here I'm trying to convert .foo files to .baz files with the convertFoos utility, but to do so I need to manipulate the `%%A` string to remove both file extensions, which I can't figure out how to do. I know that one `~n` removes one extension, but two don't seem to remove two like I expected and I can't find a good way to do it. I would like to avoid scanning the folder for .foo files again as I might want to leave other .foo files in there untouched, but if there's no other reasonable way to do it I can avoid having other .foo files in the same folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the   extension part twice, by making a `call`, that reinterprets its arguments:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (bars.txt) do decompressBars.exe %%A

for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (bars.txt) do call :convertFoos "%%~nA"

::Code should continue here

::Prevent reaching the "method"
exit /b

:convertFoos
convertFoos.exe %1 "%~n1.baz"
exit /b
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, and I would say made my code more legible. I'm not sure why you're getting negative votes, it seems like a great solution.